# Error using "#" in macro

Tags: c

I am trying to clean up an existing code and I did format the below Macro from

```
#define v(x) { if (!is_visited(n->line) && ANNOTATE_SOURCE) { visit(n->line); sprintf(buffer, "#\n# LINE %d: %s#\n", n->line, get_line(n->line)); program = emit(program, buffer); }}
```

to

```
#define v(x) {\
               if (!is_visited(n->line) && ANNOTATE_SOURCE)\ 
               {\ 
                  visit(n->line);\
                  sprintf(buffer, "#\n# LINE %d: %s#\n", n->line,get_line(n->line));\ 
                  program = emit(program, buffer);\
                }\
             }\
```

and I got `error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter`

I searched through the forums and I could not understand why this error occurs though I am not trying to use any Macro within any other Macro.

Edit:

I tried to do `sprintf(buffer, "\#\n\# LINE %d: %s\#\n", n->line,get_line(n->line));` (Adding escape character to #. still the same error persists)

Comment: Where is `ANNOTATE_SOURCE` defined? Did you copy paste the macro from your text editor?

Comment: It is a global defined in a different source file(main.c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure `\` is the last character of your line before the new-line character. This is not the case in your program: there are whitespaces after `\`.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro has spaces after the continuation character `\`, that's not allowed

```
#define v(x) do {                                                             \
        if (!is_visited(n->line) && ANNOTATE_SOURCE)                          \
        {                                                                     \
          visit(n->line);                                                     \
          sprintf(buffer, "#\n# LINE %d: %s#\n", n->line, get_line(n->line)); \
          program = emit(program, buffer);                                    \
        }                                                                     \
    } while (0)
```

As you can see above, I also used a `do {} while (0)` loop that doesn't loop to allow using a `;` after the macro invocation,

```
v(a);
```

is now valid.